# array inside array android

Tags: java, android

I dont know how to do this. But what i want is to create a two array.. one for the array class then the other is for the information that i will use for the selected class using for loop. I prefer for loop that for each loop.. ^_^.. My question is. Is it posible to create an array in which it will store an array too? for example:

```
private final Class<?>[] cls = {class1,class2,class3};
private final String[] myFirstArray = {array1[],array2[],array[]3};
private final String selectedarray[];

for(int i=0;i<cls.lenght();i++){
if(myArrayClassParameter == cls[i]){
selectedArray[] = myFirstArray[i];
}
}
```

Like that?

Well If it is posible my work will be less time consuming.. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely - you can create arrays of arrays, or even arrays of arrays of arrays, and so on. All you need is to add more pairs of square brackets `[]`.

```
private final String[][] firstArray = new String[][] {
    new String[] {"quick", "brown", "fox"}
,   new String[] {"jumps", "over", "the"}
,   new String[] {"lazy", "dog", "!"}
};

String[] selectedArray = firstArray[1];
```

Comment: BTW Can i put three[]? hehe.. Awesome

Comment: @thenewbie Absolutely - as many as you need, Java does not have any specific limit.

Comment: @thenewbie You should know that these are available in almost every programming language as well. They're very useful.

Comment: @Tushar Dhoot i think visual basic dont have that

Answer (score 2):

Yes. These are called [multidimensional arrays](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/java_multi_dimensions_array.shtml). Try them out and mess around with them. You'll learn better that way.

You must declare them like this:

```
Type[] smallerArray1;
Type[] smallerArray2;
Type[] smallerArray3;
Type[][] biggerArray = new Type[][]{smallerArray1, smallerArray2, smallerArray3};
```

Then you can use them like regular arrays.